# I’m getting little more than 12 V in my computer PSU, should I use it?

Tags: power-supply, computers

I bought a refurbished computer ATX PSU, it had the most generic PCB I have ever witnessed. Seems like has a optocoupler and works with sdc2921 IC.

In **12 V** rail I’m getting **12.25 V.**

In **5 V** I’m getting **5.33 V.**

In **3.3** getting **3.27** (seems ok).

And also I load tested 12 V rail it seems to work fine till 14 A without any problem. Should I use it or not, how much volt can be **tolerated** in such PSU?

Thank you :)

Comment: +2% is good......

Comment: We don't know what are your loading conditions for the supply. The 5V rail exceeds tolerance requirements but if there is no load at all then it would not be surprising to see too high voltages. We also can't say if you should use a refurbished ATX PSU, we don't know how old it is or how long it works before it breaks. If you don't care if it damages all your components then you can use it. If you do care, think if you want to take the risk or not.

Comment: How’s the battery in your multimeter?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's fine. The [specification](https://xdevs.com/doc/Standards/ATX/ATX12V_Power_Supply_Design_Guide_Rev1.1.pdf) is as follows:

[image]

Edit: Allowable load conditions for the power supply to meet specifications. Note the 1A minimum on the 5V rail. The voltages are measured at the **end** of the output load connectors, under load. Only the 3.3V rail has sense feedback so resistive losses
(as well as load regulation) subtract from the other voltages.

[image]

I would be mostly concerned to see that it contains proper OVP, as the specification requires. Also, investigate whether "refurbished" mean they replaced the fan or not, because in my personal experience cooling fan failures are the major root cause of PSU failures.

Comment: Excuse me but 5.33V is more than limit of 5.25V

Comment: @Justme **minimum** load on the 5V rail is 1A.  It can go higher if that requirement is ignored.

Comment: @Justme it probably decreases when you plug in some components that use power.

Comment: They actually took the atx case from garbage, looks like the case atleast got impacted from a free fall of 10 story or a truck ran over it. The pcb is the kinda of board you get from a drug dealer (i have never seen a board like this, smaler than the case). Fan runs but but.... there is a catch i ran the supply ideally for 20 min . Without any load the three transistor in primary side (13007 x2 , c3866 connected to same heatsink) heats like 50 degree without any load .

Comment: To me, that sounds like you should return it from whence it came.

Comment: Got for 350rs less than 5$ . Traveling far itself 2 $ and other things will round up to 4$ should i waste 4$ to return a 5$  supply??  Do you have any idea why the primary transistor heats even when it is ideal cuz this guy goin in my server

Comment: I mean throw it in the garbage. Do you get your motherboards and electrical energy for free?